# Get to command line from arch cinnamon

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, gnome, cinnamon

I have a new arch install with Gnome Window Manager and Cinnamon. I created ~/.xinitrc with the command `start cinnamon`, and restarted the computer.

Now the system boots into the login screen for Gnome and Cinnamon, but there is no command line shell available in the GUIs, and I'm unable to boot the computer into command line mode either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in cinnamon or gnome there is terminal application. If there is no such application, then install it.
But if you wan to get back to tty just press ctrl+alt+F1 (or any other F in range 1-6)